# Including Parentheses in a Concatenate String Throws "Unterminated String Constant"

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a VBScript/HTA to list printers in a for loop.

```
document.write("<BUTTON onclick=SetDefaultPrinter('" & objItem.Name & "')>" & objItem.Name & "</BUTTON><BR>")
```

The loop is to create buttons with the text being the name of the printer and the onclick event to have the value that should pass to the procedure.

I'm expecting the printed code to be

```
<BUTTON onclick=SetDefaultPrinter('Ms Print to PDF')>MS Print to PDF</BUTTON>
```

Tried different methods such as adding chr(40) and chr(41) instead of bracket but nobody what I try, I get an error.

Either

```
Expected: ')'
```

or

```
Unterminated string constant
```

Putting the exact same code into a MsgBox prints the desired results. Can someone help explain to what is wrong? I want to know why it is wrong, what is the correct way, and why. 
Everything has its matching quote or bracket and what I can find on Google, nested brackets are fine in strings like this. So I really don't understand why its giving an error. When I run the script, it still outputs the html but throws the script error.

Note: I'm kinda expecting someone to question other aspects of my code. I'll admit I'm not the strongest coder and will welcome advice. Such as passing a value to SetPrinterDefault(); doubting the way I'm doing it is correct. In my defense, I'm trying to get this problem working first then test if I am passing the value to it correctly. Learning it as I go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line to

`document.write("<BUTTON onclick=""SetDefaultPrinter('" & objItem.Name & "')"">" & objItem.Name & "</BUTTON><BR>")`

The problem is `objItem.Name` returns a string with spaces. So you have to use single or double quote while calling the function when `onClick` event is fired.

You can also use the following code to achieve the same

`document.write("<BUTTON onclick='SetDefaultPrinter(""" & objItem.Name & """)'>" & objItem.Name & "</BUTTON><BR>")`

Or if you want to add double quote using `Chr`

`document.write("<BUTTON onclick='SetDefaultPrinter(" & Chr(34) & objItem.Name & Chr(34) & ")'>" & objItem.Name & "</BUTTON><BR>")`

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it now.